# Apache Marathon app and container relation

Tags: marathon

I would like to understand the relation between a Marathon App and a container. Is it really so, that a Marathon App definition can contain only a single container definition (1:1)? As far as I understand the Marathon REST API, link attached, the answer is yes.

https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#post-/v2/apps

But then are we supposed to use App Groups in order to define such complex applications that are built from more than a single container? I have checked Kubernetes, and the idea of "pod" in that case seems to be very convenient to build such applications, that are composed by multiple containers, which containers in the same pod have a single network stack, and application scaling happens on pod level.

Can we say, that Kubernetes pod corresponds to Marathon App Group? Or should I not try to find any similarities, but rather I should better understand Marathon philosophy?

Thank you!

Regards,

Laszlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app in Marathon specifies how to spawn tasks of that application. While you can specify how many tasks you want to spawn, every single on of these tasks only corresponds to one command or container.

To help you, I would need to understand more about your use case.

Groups can be used to organize related apps including dependencies. The tasks of the apps will not necessarily be co-located on the same host.

If you need co-location, you need to either create a container with multiple processed or use constraints to directly specify on which host you want to run the tasks.